# where the log files stored - filebeat and logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have installed the ELK with Filebeat.

I followed this blog for setup : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04#set-up-filebeat(add-client-servers)

When I tested with:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'
```

I got the result as the blog.

There are two question from my side:

1. After the logstash host got the log info, where it stored?
2. If I want to use the filebeat to forward the whole log file to the logstash host and stored the location which I desired, how can I config it?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash sends its output where you configure it to.  In the blog posting you reference, the file 30-elasticsearch-output.conf contains an output{} section, which directs the output to elasticsearch.  There are lots of other possible outputs.

Comment: In fact I have added the path in the output file.                                  
output {
if [type] == 'syslog'{
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
sniffing => true
manage_template => false
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
path => "/var/log/filebeat"
}
}
}  

And service also restart. But it not works.

I am not sure whether I should also edit some entries of the filebeat config file.

Comment: I think it's pretty rare than any config you find in a blog post is going to do everything that you need done, which makes it important to learn how the system works and build up your own config iteratively.  To see what logstash might be sending to elasticsearch, try adding a stdout{} output section.